# Angular md-tab needs more space to display tabs

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-material

I have a limited width of 300px. There I need to display two tabs (A & B) and space is enough to show A & B as tab.

When used Angular md-tab-group, it automatically shows arrow icons with tab and to select another tab, I need to click arrow button multiple times.
[image]

Since tab names are very small, it should show the tabs.

```
<md-tab-group class="tab-group">
  <md-tab label="A">
    TAB A
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="B">
    TAB B
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Comment: is it not responsive?? it must shrink itself

Comment: Is it for material1 or material2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming its for material2, I found that by default material2 tabs are set to `min-width: 160px`. Since your screen size is only `300px`, you will need to change the `min-width` to `100px` or some other measurement that suits your need.

I tested it following [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/k2MrAPGI94bYB8UW60bw?p=preview) and was able to fit both tabs within `300px` without any scrolling arrows. You can use it to find the correct size you need.

html:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 500px; border: solid 1px black">
  <md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="TAB A" style="min-width: 100px">Content 1</md-tab>
    <md-tab label="TAB B" style="min-width: 100px">Content 2</md-tab>
  </md-tab-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `disablePagination` worked for me:

try

```html
<md-tab-group class="tab-group" disablePagination>
  <md-tab label="A">
    TAB A
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="B">
    TAB B
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```